# Nickel plating with nickel acetate, nickel chloride, sulfur, saccharin and coumarin

Tags: home-experiment, electroplating

I am a hobbyist trying to learn/apply a nickel electroplating process that I can safely do at my shop.  My substrate is a machinable non-stainless steel with unknown carbon content, and I'm looking to do a close variation of the "Watts Bright nickel" formula.  I have a 99.9% pure nickel anode, nickel acetate, nickel chloride, boric acid, sulfur powder, saccharin and coumadin powders.

The formula calls for nickel sulfate; is it possible to simply add the powdered Sulfur to the solution, or do I have to use a different process to synthesize the nickel sulfate? If so,  can I do so with the materials that I have? 
Also, the Watts formula does not include the saccharin or coumarin, but I know that these chemical additives will increase the odds of a smooth mirror like finish.

Also, is there a recommended quantity range, or at least a starting point, for these two chemicals for this application? Any insights here from an experienced chemist/electroplater would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> The formula calls for nickel sulfate; is it possible to simply add the powdered sulfur to the solution, or do I have to use a different process to synthesize the nickel sulfate?

This will not work. Sulfur ($\ce{S}$) and sulfate ($\ce{SO4^{2-}}$) are two pairs of shoes. The oxidation state is different and there is no way that sulfur powder will turn into sulfate during the electroplating.

> If so, can I do so with the materials that I have?

It might be possible to heat another nickel salt in sulfuric acid, cool down and wait for the nickel sulfate to precipitate, but **I wouldn't do it!**

Given that the nickel salts are highly toxic, might cause cancer on inhalation and are harmful for aquatic organisms, I wouldn't mess around with crystallisation and the remaining solution for which you would have to find a safe way for disposal.

It might be much easier to aquire nickel sulfate and set up the bath for electroplating according to the given specifications.

Comment: That is very helpful.  Thanks.  So, I was now looking at doing the Conventional Sulfamate method.  How is Nickel Sulfamate different from Nickel Sulfate?  And I am curious if this chemical is easier/safer, or more challenging/dangerous to synthesize.  Also, can I do this synthesis with Nickel Acetate, Sulfur, and/or Nickel Sulfate?

Comment: I just asked a similar question about the possibility of using NiMH as an anode for Nickel plating. Please help.